# How to NSLog() a periphal?

Tags: ios, ios6, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I'm having trouble identifying what a peripheral is which would normally lead me to be able to NSLog() it properly.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals {
  NSLog(@"discovered peripherals: %@", howToListPeriphalsForDebugging);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with above `NSLog`? If I am correct `CBPeripheral` is a pointer and you can use it with `%@`.

Comment: I'm looking into this more.  I'm actually not even getting there right now...

Comment: Did you try: `NSLog(@"discovered peripherals: %@", peripherals);`? It appears the array is an array of `CBPeripheral` objects.

Comment: OK, repaired to be able to test now.  You *can* just NSLog() it.

Comment: You could also, `NSLog(@"%@",[peripherals description]);`

Comment: `peripherals` is an `NSArray`. So it should be working with an %@. You could also enumerate the NSArray...

Comment: @Kevin, IMHO @"%@" interpolation always calls -descriptionWithLocale: or -description.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
NSLog(@"discovered peripherals: %@", howToListPeriphalsForDebugging);
```

To:

```
NSLog(@"discovered peripherals: %@", peripherals);
```